# Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ [key: number]: any[]; }'. in React/Angular in state variable

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

i am getting following error when i try to loop the state data

**Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ [key: number]: any[]; }'.**

State declaration

```
export interface State {  
    resultData:{ [key: number]: any[] };  
}
```

class Declaration

```
export  class AccountComp extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {   
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            resultData: {}, 
        };  
    } 


update function  showing issue in second for loop .
Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ [key: number]: any[]; }'.



update = () => { 
      for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
      {   
        for (let j = 0; j < this.state.resultData.length; j++)   // showing issue in this line 
          {

          }  
      }  
    }
```

Comment: You are initializing `resultData: {}` to an object literal instead of an array literal `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface, `resultData` is not the array. `resultData[key]` is the array. So try the following

```js
update = () => { 
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
  {   
    for (let j = 0; j < this.state.resultData[i].length; j++)
    {
      // do something
    }  
  }  
}
```